# How to ensure a Step Function Control in GEKKO and confusion about MV_TYPE

Tags: python, controls, gekko, optimal

I have a simple optimal control problem where I have to find a step function *f*(*t*) to maximize an objective functional (`IMODE=6`). Now *f*(*t*) is defined for *t* in [0, 10) such that *f* takes on 10 different equi-spaced values. (i.e. *f*(*t*)=*f*<sub>0</sub> for 0 ≤ *t* < 1, etc.). Moreover *f* itself takes on only integer values in between 0 and 10 inclusive.

To start, I took `m.time=np.linspace(0, 10, 11)` to have `[0, 1, 2, ..., 10]` be the points in my time mesh. Then I took `f=m.MV(lb=0, ub=10, integer=True)` and solved with APOPT using `m.options.SOLVER = 1` and just ignored the value of *f*(10).

This resolves fine and I am able to acquire an integer solution. The result of this, it appears, is a linear interpolant of *f* instead of the step-function interpolant of *f* that I wanted. After reading documentation, I thought that MV_TYPE was the flag that I needed. So I tried switching *f* to a step-function by setting `m.options.MV_TYPE=0` but that gave me the same result as obtained by `m.options.MV_TYPE=1`. (Telling me that I completely misunderstand what MV_TYPE is supposed to do.) So for my first question: what even *is* the MV_TYPE flag doing? My read was that MV_TYPE=0 interpolates all MV variables with a step-function and MV_TYPE=1 interpolates all MV variables with a linear interpolant. However, two separate runs with both options for MV_TYPE yields identical solutions with identical objective functional values.

Secondly, is there some better way to do what I want? (Force my control to take the form of a discontinuous step function). I saw in the documentation (example #17 of 18) that the appropriate way to make a step function is basically to make the time mesh fine enough to cover the seam. Indeed, something like `m.time=[0, 0.999, 1, 1.999, 2, 2.999, ..., 9, 9.999]` would be a reasonable mesh for me. However, then my `f=m.MV` line would result in `f` having 20 independent values (instead of the 10 that I would like). Is there anyway to force the MV to take the same value at the time points `t=0` and `t=0.999` (and the same value at `t=1` and `t=1.999` etc.) in order to ensure that my function is a step-function?

I can't help but feel like I'm missing something obvious here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of `MV_TYPE` is correct. From the [document for MV_TYPE](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmMvType):

*MV_TYPE specifies either a zero order hold (0) or a first order linear (1) interpolation between the MV endpoints. When the MV_STEP_HOR is two or greater, the MV_TYPE is applied only to each segment where adjustments are allowed. The MV segment is otherwise equal to the prior time segment. The MV_TYPE only influences the solution when the number of NODES is between 3 and 6. It is not important when NODES=2 because there are no interpolation nodes between the endpoints.*

It is likely giving the same answer because `m.options.NODES=2` by default. Setting `m.options.NODES>=3` will likely cause problems for integer type MVs with `MV_TYPE=1` because the linear interpolating points also need to be integers. If you still want to use `NODES=2` but need more simulation resolution then try something like:

```py
m.time = [0,0.5,0.9999,1,1.5,1.9999,2,2.5,2.9999,3]
```